`__has_include` macro on ESP board
I am working on a code for ESP boards that can be used on either ESP32 or ESP8266 and I want to make sure I include the correct libraries.
I know I can check if ESP32 OR ESP8266 are defined, but I wanted something more specific.
Anyway, in my project I have a class called Storage which provides an interface for a storage medium, and two implementations: one with the Preferences library and another with SPIFFS.
I want to have instantiation functions for each implementation (sort-of factory pattern), and to use pre-compilation checks to only compile the valid implementations for the currently selected board.
This is my current code:
#include <memory.h>
#include "Storage.h"

#if __has_include(<Preferences.h>)
#include "PreferencesStorage.h"
std::unique_ptr<Storage> createPreferencesStorage() {
    return std::make_unique<PreferencesStorage>();
}
#endif

#if #if __has_include(<SPIFFS.h>)
#include "SpiffsStorage.h"
std::unique_ptr<Storage> createSpiffsStorage() {
    return std::make_unique<SpiffsStorage>();
}
#endif


My problem is that #if __has_include(<Preferences.h>)returns false for some reason even though I can import the library.
It only returns true if I first include <Preferences.h> which obviously is not really helpful.
Does anyone have idea what might be the cause?

here's a two year old post https://github.com/arduino/arduino-cli/issues/1782
